# Rails double nested routes, broken up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I have these routes:

```
  map.resources :categories do |category|
    category.resources :sub_categories
  end

  map.resources :sub_categories do |sub_category|
    sub_category.resources :events
  end
```

This is only so that the url doesnt have to be doubly nested, I want to keep the url to a max of two objects deep.

**The problem** is that for events, **I want to require there to a /sub_categories/:sub_category_id as a path_prefix**, but using

```
  map.resources :events, path_prefix => '/sub_categories/:sub_category_id'
```

gives me routes like

```
  event_path
```

***What I want to have is***

```
  sub_category_event_path
```

BECAUSE any time a user wants to get to a *sub_category*, i want the url to require a *category_id* be provided, but if a user wants to see an event, a sub_category_id must be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to get this working.. but I'm going to leave it here in hopes of people voting for a custom helper as @wuputah suggested, or my method.

```
map.resources :events, :path_prefix => 'sub_categories/:sub_category_id', :name_prefix => 'sub_category_'
```

produces the routes I'm looking for..

Comment: fwiw, that changes its name, but not the arguments it accepts.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it does generate `event_path`, but that `event_path` will require a `:sub_category_id` option. To get a `sub_category_event_path` helper, just write one:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def sub_category_event_path(sub_category, event) 
    event_path(event, :sub_category_id => sub_category)
  end
  helper_method :sub_category_event_path
end
```

Unfortunately, if you ever want `sub_category_event_url`, you'll have to write that one too.

Rails 3 does have some new support for shallow routes that might interest you. Consider upgrading!